# UV Mapping a Texture onto a Plane with a Tif

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-coordinates

I have an image.png file that I need to use as a texture for a plane. However, I also have a tif file that stores the coordinates for the UV mapping. Inside the stif the data is stored in a 960x1280x2 matrix, where each of the matrix[x][y] is a pixel in the image.png file. How can I make the image correspond to the tif file.

I haven't been able to find anything on this. Thank so so much.

Comment: Unless you're capable of writing a Python script that creates a UV map from this in Blender or somebody does that for you, I don't think there is an easy way. Perhaps it's easier to unwrap the model in Blender and try to approximate the UV layout.

Comment: I am capable of writing a python script, I just dont understand conceptually how to do it properly.

Comment: Just for clarification the texture is for a plane as in airplane or a simple rectangular surface?

Comment: @rjg regular surface

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to load the image into the UV editor and simply match the four vertices after unwrap to the edges?